# Unable to load asset in Alert Dialog content

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog, flutter-assetimage

I know that there are a lot of thread related to this question but they didn't help.
I have an asset folder containing images. Images are properly shown in other parts of the code but not in the Alert Dialog. In the example I use a .gif file, but I had the same problem also with .png.

**Error from Debug Console**

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: check.gif

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:225
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:668
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:651
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:504
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "check.gif")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#234cb(), name: "check.gif", scale: 1.0)
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

I already tried using /assets/check.gif but I had the same problem.

**Code**

```
 showDialog(
                                                  context: context,
                                                  builder:
                                                      (BuildContext context) {
                                                    return AlertDialog(
                                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                            borderRadius:
                                                                BorderRadius
                                                                    .all(Radius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                            13)),
                                                            side: BorderSide(
                                                                color: const Color(
                                                                    0xff5387ff),
                                                                width: 3)),
                                                        content: Container(
                                                          height: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                      context)
                                                                  .size
                                                                  .height /
                                                              9,
                                                          child: Column(
                                                            children: [
                                                              Image.asset(
                                                                'check.gif',
                                                                width: 20,
                                                                height: 20,
                                                                fit: BoxFit
                                                                    .contain,
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ));
                                                  });
```

**Output:**

[image: My AlertDialog]

Hope you'll be albe to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your `folder path`. Like where you `store your assets` that folder path and your asset name. Like the below

```
             Image.asset(
              'assets/check.gif',
              width: 20,
              height: 20,
              fit: BoxFit
                  .contain,
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this, I think you forgot to add *"assets"* in Widget

```html
 Image.asset('assets/check.gif', width: 20,height: 20,fit:BoxFit.contain,),
```